# Forecasting/Predicition for a specific date

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

First of all data science is not my experties so apologies if this sounds stupid.

I have a data X that is either 1 or 0 and (possibly) dependent on some other variables. I have the values for these variables mesured at specific dates. Given a date, I need to predict whether X will be 1 or 0 on that day in the futire.

I checked logistic regression which seems to fit my definition (multiple independent variables, binary result). The problem is that none of the agorithms take date as a parameter. They all try to predict a given value which I dont want.

How do I forecast for any given date?

**EDIT:** Given

Traffic Volume (float),
Active Users (integer),
Throughput (float)

Congestion Flag (0 or 1) (we need to forecast this)

Comment: Hi there, you should checkout FB's Prophet Library

Comment: for you r problem time series will work easily...can u try ARIMA

Comment: please post any sample data

Comment: @saisaran Please see the edit for a more detailed description of the data. Do you need real values?

Comment: i  am checking and will let u know if anything